# How to aggregate dataframe by user with session-scope complexity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my dataframe:

```
current_df=
[userid, sessionid, date, session_number, purchase_activity]
[1, 20, 01-01-2019, 10, 1]
[1, 21, 01-03-2019, 11, 1]
[2, 22, 01-01-2019, 1,  1]
[3, 23, 01-09-2019, 3,  0]
```

Note:
seesionid = unique id
purchase_activity is binary, 1 means user did a purchase and 0 means no purchase.

```
  desired_df=
    [userid, first_date, last_date, total_sessions, total_purchase_activity]
    [1, 01-01-2019, 01-03-2019,11, 2]
    [2, 01-01-2019, 01-01-2019, 1, 1]
    [3, 01-09-2019, 01-09-2019, 3, 0]
```

How would I aggregate in such way in creating new columns at the same time so that I only have 1 row for a unique user? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try: `df.groupby('userid').agg({'date':'max', 'session_number':'max', 'purchase_activity':'sum'})`